# Javascript button working but not in my partner laptop

Tags: javascript, custom-button, list-button

I have javacript list button on custom object payment to create child object under opportunity. The code running as expected, but not in my partner laptops. I try enable javascript on their browser but still not working.

here my javascript code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
var PaymentCheck = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Payment__c WHERE Opportunity__c = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");
var records = PaymentCheck.getArray("records");
if(records.length>0){
    alert('Opportunity already has payment');
}
else
{
    //Identify Opty Object
    var oppty = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
    oppty.id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
    oppty.PaymentScheme = "{!Opportunity.Payment_Scheme__c}";
    if("{!Opportunity.Tuition_Fee_after_Discount_IDR__c}" != "") {oppty.FinalAmount = '{!TEXT(Opportunity.Tuition_Fee_after_Discount_IDR__c)}';} 
    if("{!Opportunity.Amount_IDR__c}" != "") {oppty.AmountIDR = '{!TEXT(Opportunity.Amount_IDR__c)}';} 
    if("{!Opportunity.Development_Fee_after_Disc__c}" != "") {oppty.DevelopmentFeeIDR = '{!TEXT(Opportunity.Development_Fee_after_Disc__c)}';}
    if("{!Opportunity.getProductName__c}" != "") {oppty.ProductName = '{!Opportunity.getProductName__c}';}
    oppty.StudentId = "{!Opportunity.Student_NameId__c}";

    if (oppty.PaymentScheme == "")
    {
        alert("Payment Scheme Not Selected");
    }
    else if(oppty.AmountIDR ==0)
    {
        alert("Please Add Program Before Generate The Payment");
    }
    else if(oppty.DevelopmentFeeIDR == 0 && (oppty.ProductName!='Grade 10 Annual' || oppty.ProductName!='Grade 10 Quarterly' || oppty.ProductName!='Grade 10 Monthly'))
    {
        alert("Please Fill Development Fee IDR Before Generate The Payment");
    }
    else 
    {   
        var FirstPayment = new sforce.SObject("Payment__c");
        var NextPayment = new sforce.SObject("Payment__c");
        //var PaymentName = ["First Payment","Second Payment","Third Payment","Fourth Payment","Fifth Payment","Sixth Payment","Seventh Payment","Eighth Payment","Ninth Payment","Tenth Payment","Eleventh Payment","Twelfth Payment"];
        var createRecordsNextPayment = [];

        //Create Deposit payment
        var DepositPayment = new sforce.SObject("Payment__c");
        DepositPayment.Name = "Deposit (10% of Total Fee Before Discount)";
        DepositPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
        DepositPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
        DepositPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Deposit";
        DepositPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
        DepositPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.Deposit;
        DepositPayment.Term__c=0;
        sforce.connection.create([DepositPayment]);


        // Create Annual Payment
        if (oppty.PaymentScheme == "Annual")
        {   
            FirstPayment.Name = "First Instalment";
            FirstPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            FirstPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            FirstPayment.Payment_Type__c = "First Instalment";
            FirstPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            FirstPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount;
            FirstPayment.Term__c=1;
            sforce.connection.create([FirstPayment]);   
        }
        // Create Quarterly Payment
        else if (oppty.PaymentScheme == "Quarterly")
        {
            FirstPayment.Name = "First Instalment";
            FirstPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            FirstPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            FirstPayment.Payment_Type__c = "First Instalment";
            FirstPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            FirstPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 4;
            FirstPayment.Term__c=1;
            sforce.connection.create([FirstPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Second Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 4;
            NextPayment.Term__c=2;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Third Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 4;
            NextPayment.Term__c=3;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Fourth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 4;
            NextPayment.Term__c=4;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);        
        }
        // Create Monthly Payment
        else if (oppty.PaymentScheme == "Monthly")
        {
            FirstPayment.Name = "First Instalment";
            FirstPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            FirstPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            FirstPayment.Payment_Type__c = "First Instalment";
            FirstPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            FirstPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            FirstPayment.Term__c=1;
            sforce.connection.create([FirstPayment]);


            NextPayment.Name = "Second Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=2;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]); 


            NextPayment.Name = "Third Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=3;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Fourth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=4;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Fifth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=5;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Sixth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=6;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Seventh Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=7;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Eighth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=8;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Ninth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=9;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Tenth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=10;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Eleventh Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=11;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);

            NextPayment.Name = "Twelfth Instalment";
            NextPayment.Student_Name__c = oppty.StudentId;
            NextPayment.Opportunity__c = oppty.id;
            NextPayment.Payment_Type__c = "Next Instalment";
            NextPayment.Payment_Method__c = "Transfer";
            NextPayment.Payment_Amount_IDR_SA__c = oppty.FinalAmount / 12;
            NextPayment.Term__c=12;
            sforce.connection.create([NextPayment]);
        }
        window.parent.location.href = "/"+oppty.id; 
    }
}
```

i don't know why my code works well in my laptop but not in my partner laptop,
is there any consideration that i miss using Javascript in salesforce ?

Regards,

Brian

Comment: It would really help if you describe what actually goes wrong: what error message do you get etc. Also, what is the difference between your laptop and your partners laptop? What browser do you use?

Comment: Hi @WillemMulder, i use chrome and firefox, my "a" partner use chrome,firefox,safari (not working),  my "a" partner use firefox(not working) but work with chrome

Comment: And still the most important: what error message do you get? And what did you try yourself to debug it?